# Automatically generating Piratespeak .po/gettext/translations for i18n testing?

Tags: python, django, internationalization, translation, gettext

I am working on translating our django webapp. I'd like to test that our system is set up correctly before paying a translator to do the actual translation.

Is there anyway, given a `.po` file, to automatically generate some new translations? And just for fun, is there anyway to do this to pirate speak? :) (Or some other command line text munglying tool?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out no-one has done this before. So I wrote a python script to do it myself to [piratify a .po file](http://www.technomancy.org/python/pirate-po-l10n-i18n-translate-your-site/)

Answer (score 2):

I tweeked existing auto translators to use microsoft's service instead of google's after google translation became paid service

You can find python code here -

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2679/

With the just effort of 1 hour I wrote this django app to translate the po file online. You can find the website here -

http://potranslate.prabhatgupta.com/

I hoope it helps.

Comment: I tried the online service, but it just gives a "404 not found" error.